# How to add rows using SSIS 2008 Script Component during transform?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, transform, script-component

I have a SSIS 2008 script component which is setup as a transform (so it has an input and output), and what I want to do is take 1 row in an input and optionally output multiple rows.

In 2005 there was the [AddRow and CreateNewOutputRows](http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Script-Component-as-a-Transformation.aspx) methods but those seem not to be available in 2008.

So how do I add rows during the transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you have the component configured as a synchronous transform.  If you do, you won't be able to add "extra" rows on the output.

If that's not the case, however, then all the facilities of 2005 are present in 2008.  This includes the CreateNewOutputRows method, which I don't think you want in this case.  It also includes the AddRow method - which will only be available on an output buffer, probably named Output0Buffer, which you won't see if your output is synchronous.

Review [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx) to set up an asynchronous script.